# All pages and products redirect to wrong store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url-rewrite, redirect, multidomain

Magento CE 1.9.1.0 - Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS VPS

We had a wholesale store and just recently launched a retail store.  For some reason, now all pages and products from the wholesale store are now redirecting to the retail store.  Under the CMS pages settings for each page, and in the URL rewrite management settings for each product belonging to the wholesale store, I've verified that each page/product is set to use the wholesale store view.  I've also made sure to clear all caches and cache storage along with reindexing all data.  I can confirm that the Apache is not causing the rewrites because hovering over a product or page from the admin page shows the retail store URL.  The homepage for the wholesale store does work, however, any subsequent links are going to the wrong store.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you did not change the base urls in the system config but it is difficult to make an accurate pronostic without any example of url or store.